# Unable to create a table with foreign key. Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, identifier, ora-00904

I am trying to create a table that has a foreign key in a table called 'country' which looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE country (
   name varchar2(50),
   region varchar2(60),
   area number(10,0),
   population number(11,0),
   gdp number,
   CONSTRAINT country_PK primary key (name)
 );
```

Every time I try to reference the 'country' in my 'City' create table I get this error ORA-00904: : invalid identifier.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE City(
CityName varchar2(50) not null,
CityCountry varchar2(60),
CityPopulation number(11,0),
IsCapital char(1),
CONSTRAINT CityName_pk PRIMARY KEY (CityName),
CONSTRAINT CityCountry_fk FOREIGN KEY (CityCountry) REFERENCES country (name),
);
```

Comment: The invalid identifier is the superfluous `,` at the end of your foreign key constraint. Omit it and your foreign key will work.

Comment: in `country` table your PK is `name varchar2(50)` and in `City` table your FK is `CityCountry varchar2(60)` - try having 50 or 60 in both - even if this is not what causes problem its not a good idea to have as different type size columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the trailing comma `,` from your last line of `Country` table DDL

```
CONSTRAINT CityCountry_fk FOREIGN KEY (CityCountry) REFERENCES country (name),
```

should become:

```
CONSTRAINT CityCountry_fk FOREIGN KEY (CityCountry) REFERENCES country (name)
```